# How to use a php variable id in a jquery function?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Below code works for value(`B`) in `select#B` but NOT for a variable(`$index`) in `select#index`.
Actually I need `id` to be a variable and want a jQuery function to operate on that variable.

### jquery function:

```
$(function(){

    $('select#B').change(function(){

        var this_value = $(this).val();

            $('input#seleted_value').val(this_value);

    });

});
```

Comment: There's no PHP in that code, so that's probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: All of the answers here presume you're able to parse php within your javascript, which may not be the case. One alternative is to output the variable value to a hidden input field, and then use jQuery to retrieve and use it in your selector.

Comment: Below is the PHP code calling the jquery function: <?php $A = array('B','C','D','E'); $index= $A[0]; ?> <select name='abc' id = <?php echo $index; ?> onchange="change_val()"> <?php foreach($A as $key=>$val) { echo "<option value='$key '>$val</option>"; <br/>} ?> </select> <input name="seleted_value" id="seleted_value" value="Hello first time" >

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$("select#<?php echo $index;?>").change(function(){
     var this_value = $(this).val();

     $('input#seleted_value').val(this_value);
});
```

Comment: $('select#'+<?php echo $index;?>).change(function(){
     var this_value = $(this).val();

     $('input#seleted_value').val(this_value);
});   did not work

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
$("select#<?php echo $index;?>").change(function(){

var this_value = $(this).val();

    $('input#seleted_value').val(this_value);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('select#<?=$index?>').change(function(){
```

OR

```
 $('select#<?PHP echo $index;?>').change(function(){
```

Comment: Will single qoutes parse $index?

Comment: @chandresh_cool yes, the single quotes aren't part of the php

Answer (score 0):

```
   var selector = 'select#<?= $index ?>'; // Work only if short tag is enabled

    OR

    var selector = 'select#<?php echo $index ?>'; 

    $(selector).change(function(){
```